# wp_list_pages: only show subpages on the parent page?

Tags: menus, pages, wp-list-pages, sub-menu

I'm using `wp_list_pages('title_li=')` on my site.

Some of my pages do have subpages, however I don't want to list them unitl I'm on an actual parent page that has subpages.

So imagine my front-page:

```
— About Us
— Gallery
— Kitchen
— Disclaimer
```

When clicking on Gallery (and Gallery has two subpages) I want them to be listed as well.

```
— About Us
— Gallery
  — Subpage 1
  — Subpage 2
— Kitchen
— Disclaimer
```

How am I going to do this with the `wp_list_pages()` function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This would probably be better achieved using CSS. First, you hide all .children:

```
.page_item .children {
  display: none;
}
```

Then, you show the current_page_item's children:

```
.current_page_item .children {
  display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try the following:

```
$output = wp_list_pages(depth=1);
```

expl:
 **depth** 
    (integer) This parameter controls how many levels in the hierarchy of pages are to be included in the list generated by wp_list_pages. The default value is 0 (display all pages, including all sub-pages).

```
    0 (default) Displays pages at any depth and arranges them hierarchically in nested lists
    -1 Displays pages at any depth and arranges them in a single, flat list
    1 Displays top-level Pages only
    2, 3 … Displays Pages to the given depth
```

For mor info can have a look [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_list_pages)